# Unexpected Python class variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've ran into this behavior a couple times in Python and it's a little puzzling.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, initial_data={}):
        self.data = initial_data

instance_a = MyClass()
instance_a.data['key1'] = 'val1'
print("instance_a.data:", instance_a.data)

instance_b = MyClass()
print("instance_b.data:", instance_b.data)
```

With the output:

```
instance_a.data: {'key1': 'val1'}
instance_b.data: {'key1': 'val1'}
```

I would expect `data` to act as an instance variable, but it looks like in this case it acts as a class variable.

Does anyone know exactly why this happens and what's the best practice to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When assigning `self.data = initial_data`, you just create another new name for the object `initial_data`.

The behavior you didn't expect here is caused by the fact that the default argument `initial_data` gets evaluated only once when the method gets declared, not everytime you call it, so all your instances that use it actually use the same `initial_data` dict object, that you can access under different names like `instance_a.data`, `instance_b.data` and so on.

The classic solution is to use `None` as default, like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, initial_data=None):
        if initial_data is None:
            initial_data = {}
        self.data = initial_data
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the id of the data variable is same. Functions in Python are first-class objects, and not only a piece of code.

```
print(id(instance_a.data))
# prints of object id

print(id(instance_b.data))
# prints the same object id
```

This is because of the fixed value in the parameter of the constructor. It does not create a new dictionary for each object.

On doing this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.data = {}
```

You will get different results.

Read more here: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Hope this helps, good luck.